# Remove update when location not changed in long time in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, locationmanager, locationlistener

I created an android app to get a user's location from `LocationManager` and `Locationlistener` with a GPS provider. My `minDistance` parameter in `requestLocationUpdates` is 100 (that means that the location is not updated when the distance < 100 meters), and I want to remove `updatelocation` automatically when the location is not changed (or no new location is received in `onLocationChanged`) after a long time (ex: 5 minutes), for energy saving purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Write a service to collect data from GPS. Run a thread for 5 mins in which request for GPS coordinates after every minutes, if all the reading are same in those 5 mins. Stop the service, and then you can start it again whenever you want.